# Why does Python have both a module and a class called datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm constantly getting confused about whether I have imported `datetime` from `datetime`, or whether I've just imported `datetime`.  If I see in some code that `datetime` is being used, I can't quickly tell whether it is the module datetime or the class datetime.  So annoying.  What can I do?

Also, [PEP 8 clearly states](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names): "Class names should normally use the CapWords convention."

It would help if the classes in the `datetime` module were called `DateTime`, `Date`, and `Time`.

Since this question was put on hold as "unclear what you're asking", I've decided to edit and write more.  To be honest, I wasn't sure what I was asking either -- I just found that I was repeatedly being tripped up by this issue and wanted to get feedback.  I think I did get some very helpful advice, though, especially from tdelaney:

> Personally I `import datetime as dt` and use `dt.datetime`, etc... because
>   I want to keep the original class names while minimizing the confusion
>   with the module name.

Comment: ...look at whether it's `import datetime` or `from datetime import datetime`? It should be at the top of the script. If you're getting confused, perhaps you should always use the former in your own code? Or alias it, `import datetime as dt_module` vs `from datetime import datetime as dt_class` or something.

Comment: Agree with @jonrsharpe. You should pick a convention in your code and get used to it. Personally, I always `import datetime` and then do things like `datetime.datetime.strptime(...)`. I find this useful because it allows you access to `datetime.date` and `datetime.time`.

Comment: I can't think of any significant builtin class that actually follows PEP8 in this respect: `str`, `int`, `float`, `list`, `dict`, ...because, of course, PEP8 was written *later*

Comment: Note that in terms of PEP-8, renaming existing classes would break a lot of code. Even `collections` mixes e.g. `defaultdict` and `OrderedDict`. As the PEP itself puts it *"The naming conventions of Python's library are a bit of a mess, so we'll never get this completely consistent..."*. Again, though, you can alias: `from datetime import date as Date, datetime as DateTime, time as Time`

Comment: @sapi `datetime.datetime` isn't a built-in, it's a class in the `datetime` module. If it followed PEP 8 conventions, it should be `datetime.Datetime`. The `datetime` module was added in Python 2.3, which was actually released *after* PEP 8 was written, so I don't think it's a case of it predating PEP 8. Sometimes the core developers just failed to follow their own conventions, it seems.

Comment: For what it's worth, Guido's opinion: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2009-March/073476.html

Comment: @dano I guess I was using 'builtin' a bit broadly, but to me it encompasses all of the default packages (so stuff like `re` as well).  Good point about it being introduced later, though my best guess would be the naming was for consistency.

Comment: @sapi Most standard library modules *do* follow PEP 8, though. `str`, `int`, `float`, etc. are actual  built-in types (not classes in a module in the standard library), so they have a different naming convention.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you're asking/what answer you're looking for? There are two and half questions: do you want to know why module and class share a name, why they aren't `CapWords`, *"what can [you] do"*...?

Comment: Its annoying for sure. Personally I `import datetime as dt` and use `dt.datetime`, etc... because I want to keep the original class names while minimizing the confusion with the module name. This in turn annoys a different set of people.

Comment: I disagree with the question being closed. It is clear that OP asks "why it does not follow conventions" and "what can we do about it". First, the datetime module is a bit of a mess that missed its only chance to be fixed at Python 3.0 and now there are no intensions to break the public API again (as [Guido said](https://bugs.python.org/issue5530)). Second, you can either try to live with it or fix it at your code: `from datetime import datetime as DateTime`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be nice to have more consistent naming. But the standard Python library and what are classically thought of as Python's "built in" types abide neither PEP-8 or any strict model of consistency. All of the standard types (e.g. `int`, `float`, `str`, `list`, and `dict`) are lower-case. Some extensions of `dict` are CapWorded, like `OrderedDict`. But its companion `defaultdict` is not. There are a number of data types named the same as their modules, such as `array.array` and `datetime.datetime`. The major rewrite of Python 3 moved some modules around, but it didn't homogenize or reorganize the class names to any great degree.

So...just learn to live with it. It's a historical fact, and not likely to change soon.